# Memory leak in Android for launch application (activity persisted as context)

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I have a memory leak in my android app that seems to be caused by the way the AppCompat activity stores the context of the launch activity and never releases it.

```html
Class Name                                                                        | Ref. Objects | Shallow Heap | Ref. Shallow Heap | Retained Heap
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class android.view.WindowManagerGlobal @ 0x712c48c8 System Class                  |            1 |          112 |               280 |           968
'- sDefaultWindowManager android.view.WindowManagerGlobal @ 0x32cf52e0            |            1 |           32 |               280 |           312
   '- mViews java.util.ArrayList @ 0x32cf41d8                                     |            1 |           24 |               280 |            80
      '- elementData java.lang.Object[10] @ 0x32cb0bd8                            |            1 |           56 |               280 |            56
         '- [0] com.android.internal.policy.DecorView @ 0x32e80400                |            1 |          800 |               280 |         2,368
            '- mContext android.view.ContextThemeWrapper @ 0x32f70500             |            1 |           32 |               280 |            32
               '- mBase LeakedActivity @ 0x32d44780|            1 |          280 |               280 |         4,144
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So is there anything on my side that could cause it?

Comment: Do you need to keep the launching activity on the activity stack?

Comment: @Seppl, Did you fix this issue? I have same problem like you. But I don't know how to resolve it. Please tell me if you have solution. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find a solution yet, once I found something I will update the answer